# How to find textures in a model?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm basically using Blender for the first time.

I've got a model that I downloaded from BlendSwap.  It's got (at least) a 3D mesh and some textures that came with it (which are manifestly in a subdirectory labeled "textures").  I can see the model load and applies the textures to the model.

However, I can't find the textures in Blender.  They don't appear to be in the editor labeled "Image Editor" or "UV Editor."  No matter how I scroll around or zoom in or out in those editors, I don't see anything. I have no idea how to find them.

Ultimate goal:  I need to export this blend so it can be imported into another program.  I need to check the textures to make sure they are "uv mapped" onto the mesh or the exporter or subsequent importer won't be able to find them.

Any help for a noob is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange!

It's probably safe to assume that any image textures are UV mapped onto the model, as Blender does this by default. But, there are a ways to check.

If you don't see any images in the UV or Image editors, it's because no image is selected. Let's use the UV image editor, as you want to see the UVs. At the top of the editor there will be two buttons labeled *New* and *Open*. To the immediate left  of these there is a little image icon with an arrow. Clicking this opens a menu that lists all the images in the file.

To see the UVs and how the texture applies to the model, you will have to select the specific model/section you want to look at. With your mouse in the 3D view, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode, and then <kbd>A</kbd> to make sure everything is selected.

Now go back to the UV editor and you should see the UVs. You will may have to open the appropriate image from the menu mentioned above if you want to see exactly how the UVs are laid onto that image.

Do note that this doesn't change which texture the model uses. If you want to see which textures the model uses, you will have to look at the material. To do this, switch to the *Shading* workspace, and at the bottom center you will see the shader editor. In this shader will be a network of nodes. Image texture nodes will have an orange header with the name of the texture as the title.

One other thing to note, the image files are probably packed into the .blend file. If they are, you may want to unpack them by going to *File>External Data>Unpack All Into Files* and choosing the first option.

Comment: Yup, the images are there on the image icon button.  Oddly that row of buttons is at the bottom of the UV editor, not the top.  I'm using version 2.82 (just found the "About" menu).  Tab doesn't seem to drop me into edit mode.  Is there a visual indication, or a drop down menu I could select?

Comment: Belay that, I found the edit mode button.  However "A" seems to select only a small part of the character, one bit of clothing and a weapon.  It's mapped to an image (you can obviously see it if you find the right image), but I can't figure out how to select any other part of the model.

Comment: Well, I found a kind of "properties browser" on the right, where I can look at the file contents and all of the assemblies in it (there's a lot).  If I click around that enough I can get different parts of the model to select and I can see more UV mappings.  I'll call this answered but it might be improved with a note about newer Blender versions or looking at sub assemblies in a more complex file.